# regarding viewflipper with auto-flipping

Tags: android, viewflipper

Right now I'm able flip views using sliding. I want to flip views automatically after say 5 seconds.

The code I have to flip views based on gesture recognition is:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);

                if (currentIndex == maxIndex) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
                }
                if (currentView == 0) {
                    currentView = 1;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
                    /*iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));*/
                    Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageList.get(currentIndex));
                    iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                    Log.d("image list index!!", ImageList.get(currentIndex));
                    System.gc();

                } else if (currentView == 1) {
                    currentView = 2;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.two);
                    /*iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));*/
                    Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageList.get(currentIndex));
                    iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                    Log.d("image list index!!", ImageList.get(currentIndex));

                    System.gc();
                } else {
                    currentView = 0;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zero);
                    /*iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                    */
                    Bitmap mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageList.get(currentIndex));
                    iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                    Log.d("image list index!!", ImageList.get(currentIndex));

                    System.gc();
                }
                Log.v("ImageViewFlipper", "Current View: " + currentView);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
                viewFlipper.startFlipping();
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                if (currentIndex == 0) {
                    currentIndex = maxIndex;
                } else {
                    currentIndex = currentIndex - 1;
                }
                if (currentView == 0) {
                    currentView = 2;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.two);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                    System.gc();
                } else if (currentView == 2) {
                    currentView = 1;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                    System.gc();
                } else {
                    currentView = 0;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zero);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                    System.gc();
                }
                Log.v("ImageViewFlipper", "Current View: " + currentView);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

I am flipping using viewFlipper.showNext() and showPrevious() methods now. 
I tried using

```
       viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(1000);
```

and        viewFlipper.startFlipping(); 
methods. The problem I am facing now is there are 3 imageviews I need to load one after the other in a row continuously (and images should change in each of the imageviews as they move on). This is not happening. I can see only 2 fixed images just displaying one after the other without any change in their content. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at startFlipping()
and setFlipInterval() methods in ViewFlipper class

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/03/auto-flipping-of-viewflipper.html

follow the above link.hope it helps

Comment: I already somehow figured out the same thing myself 10 minutes back. New problem..I have changed the above code to add images to viewflipper dynamically. The app is force closing due to memory issues.. Any work around?